# How can I send message to an azure queue from a 1.1 .net framework based application?

Tags: c#, .net-1.1, azure-queues, asp.net-1.1, application-integration

We need to integrate a web application based on .net framework 1.1 with an more recent application, we are thinking on using azure queues. Is that possible? There is always the option the option to poll a table, or to write a custom clinet, but we prefer not to if possible.

Comment: .NET 1.1 has been end of life for years. So upgrading is a prerequisite if you do want to integrate with "recent" applications.

Comment: Can't highlight the above comment enough. You're going to have trouble finding services which support .Net 1.1. The current Azure storage library is on 4.5. If you absolutely need 1.1 you'll have to write by hand and [access REST directly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179355.aspx).

Comment: Hate to repeat what was already said, but 1.1 is like so 10 years ago and you must upgrade your framework, which is your first step.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by folks in the comments, it would be a good idea to upgrade so you can integrate with new applications or use the REST directly https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179355.aspx. Hope that helps!